# Need Project Online to produce SSRS reports

Tags: azure, reporting-services, odata, project-online

Can someone please me or provide me with advice on the best way to follow this through. I am currently running Project Online and want to produce SSRS reports for my company. I have done some research and noticed that one way to do this could be through using an Azure VM and having SSRS installed onto it. Linking this to Project Online and having the Odata feed through the reporting database. Is this the only way or are there any one ways to get this done?